# Is there a way to change an input with a certain code

Tags: javascript, html

Is their a way to make a value of a form input change based on a certain code in another input without PHP?
EX: User puts in HFS73H into one input, and another changes to John - while another user puts JSJ39Q into the first mentioned input, and the other input changes to Paul

Comment: You should look into Javascript. Its meant for DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do.

We can encode and decode the data with Javascript.

Follow this Link
http://www.minelinks.com/supercode/2cryptoolE.html

Comment: First, an answer just pointing to some other link is bad. Second, answering a duplicate is also bad. Yes, I understand you do not have enough rep to comment, but I'd request you to keep calm until you have it. If you wish to answer, make it descriptive and self dependent enough. A reference link is good to have but just ref link is bad. Have a good day :-)